# SVN Menu not showing up in Spring tool suite

Tags: svn, subclipse, spring-tool-suite, javahl

I am working on Mac OS X Version 10.9. I have SVN Version 1.8.8 installed on this. Also I am using Subclipse 1.10.4 as a plugin in my STS. I have SVNKit v1.8.4.10145 installed as well as 
JavaHL(JNI) 1.8.8 (r1568071) installed as Client SVN Interfaces.

Unfortunately, I cannot see the SVN Menu in my STS on right clicking a JAVA file in my workspace and navigating to Team submenu.

I have tried quite a few things but nothing seems to work.

Anyone has any idea what may be issue here??

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem with Sublime after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04. I went to the repo's folder and ran: svn upgrade

Comment: Great! This one worked immediately! Upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04, using rapidsvn.

Answer (score 0):

Start with verifying you have the plugin installed.  If you open preferences can you navigate to Team > SVN.  If you see it then install is probably OK.

Is the project connected to SVN?  It does not sound like you checked out this project using Subclipse. What is on the Team menu?  Is there a Share Project menu item?  That can be used to connect to the project with Subclipse.  At that point the SVN options will appear.

Comment: I tried doing this but when I click on Share Project I get this exception:org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E155036:Working copy format of '/Users/agarg/Documents/Gateway' is too old '29',This iswhen Iselect SVNKit v1.8.4.10145 in My Preferences->Team->SVN.WhenI select JavaHL(JNI) 1.8.8 (r1568071) , I get this error org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException:The working copy needs to be upgraded svn:The working copy at '/Users/agarg/Documents/Gateway' is too old(format 29) to work with client version '1.8.8(r1568071)'(expects format 31).You need to uphrade working copy first

Comment: That does not sound unexpected.  You installed a version using SVN 1.8, your working copy is from an earlier version so SVN will not read the working copy.  Use a SVN 1.8 command line client to run svn upgrade, or do a new checkout.